# Regex for breaking repeated characters

Tags: php

I have a comment box on my site , what I want here is if a user writes input (any character) which is more than 20 characters and doesnot put space between them then it should place a space between it.

Like: "asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"

Parsed: "asdasdasdasdasdasdas dasd"

I think it can be done with string compare but I want the regex to match it or the full solution. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is called word wrapping.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

from examples :

```
<?php
$text = "A very long woooooooooooord.";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, " ", true);
echo "$newtext\n";
?>

output:

A very long wooooooo ooooord.
```

Comment: nice it is but its not breaking this :
$text = "ppppp_____asdas__ds_d__as___dasda__sdasd";

Answer (score 1):

The function `wordwrap` does this job well. But here is a regex based solution:

```
$str = "asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd";
$str = preg_replace('/(.{20})/','$1 ',$str);
```

This will put add a space even if the input is of size 20. If you don't want that use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(.{20})(?=.)/','$1 ',$str);
```